# Is it necessary to check cursor is null before closing

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I always write code like this:

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, 
        PHONE_LOOKUP_PROJECTION, null, null, null);

if (c != null) {
    if (c.moveToFirst()) { 
        bundle.contactId = c.getLong(LOOKUP_ID_COLUMN_INDEX);
        bundle.name = c.getString(LOOKUP_DISPLAY_NAME_COLUMN_INDEX);
    }


    c.close();
}
```

But i double if it is necessary to check the `c` is NULL or not. Because i feel like the value query returns always not null, even if it contains nothing.

Comment: Where does the method `getContentResolver()` come from?

Comment: This method is inside a activity. So `getContentResolver()` belongs to  activity

Comment: Is that in the Android API or from a third party library?

Comment: please check the `content resolver` `api` document, the `query` method `return` say: `A Cursor object, which is positioned before the first entry, or null`, it also depend on the `content provider's query method` implements,  the provider can return null or a empty cursor, so for the security , need check it.

Comment: @Bill: you are asking question like you have heard about android first time.Every android developer know these are android API

Comment: Very likely, but the question was not specific, and it could have been something of his own creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Believe me you **MUST** check it for null (I would have made the 'must' glow and jump around if i could), if you want to avoid cursor related crashes in the future, specially when you do requeries and data updates to your data source. You are doing it properly right now. Always check for null and always check the boolean returned by moveToFirst().